# In Excel, I am trying to populate Sheet2 with data on Sheet1 based on specific criteria

Tags: excel, filter, auto-populate

I have a master server list in Sheet1 that lists all devices we monitor (over 400). These devices have subcategories based on server roles, and I would like to auto populate additional sheets (a different sheet for each server role) so that I do not have to always filter on Sheet1 to retrieve these lists.

For example, on Sheet 1 I have the following sample table;
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QRxi.jpg)

Now, on Sheet2, I would like it to automatically list all servers with a role of "FS/DC" like so;
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KE5C.jpg)

I have searched and see similar questions asked but most of them are looking for a specific value only, whereby I want the entire row from Sheet1 to be copied to Sheet2 if Role="FS/DC".

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `searched and see similar questions` search harder. Or modify what you found.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the data? Can't use filter or other options?